# Play Framework for Scala - RESTful Web Service

Tags: scala, rest, playframework-2.0

I looked through Play framework and I am struggling to find a good documentation/tutorial
for how to do a RESTful web service in Play ver. 2+.

Please recommend any reference if you have. Googling on keywords containing "Play" and "Rest" does not give me much :-)

Comment: I think that asking for documentation, tutorials, resources is a constructive question, and I don´t find this question to open the door to endless debates...

Comment: Although it is my question, so I am subjective, I agree that this is not the first question to be closed. Documentation is part of the development process. If there is no good one, pointers from Stackoverflow become important. There is no debatable stuff there. Plus, I clearly stated that Googling will not (easily) do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should check play-mini :

https://github.com/typesafehub/play2-mini

Answer (score 10):

I'm building a backbone skeleton application, and for the backend webservice I used play 2.0 with scala.

It implements a nice json rest web service with cors, using an in-memory database

Have a look at it at:

https://github.com/opensas/BackboneBootstrap/tree/master/webservice

It support a couple of nice features, like filtering, paging, ordering and advanced queries...

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers as they both offer valuable and needed information.